# Incorporate Google Translate into Forum Textfield

Tags: php

I just started a course on php, and we have to each make and present a simple program of our choosing that takes one input and automatically generates a different output.

I chose to make a program that automatically takes a text that a user types into a forum's text field, and run it through google translate, and translates the text into another language in the same textfield, ready to edit. The problem is, when I incorporated the Google Translate API guideline according to the official Google Webmaster's guide, it translates everything EXCEPT what is inside textfields.

Anyone know if there is a way to work around it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It is nothing more than `https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&q=hello%20world&source=en&target=de`. You need to provide a key, as the Translation API is a paid service.

Comment: But is there no way to just feed a result through google translate directly, and copy the result back? It's a school project after all and it doesn't make sense to purchase a key for it.

Comment: You could `curl` the translation page and extract what is inside the `result_box`. Lookup `curl` in the php manual.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it is as easy as this, but still remains a hack:

```
<?php

    $ch = curl_init("http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=t&sl=en&tl=de&q=Hello%20World");

    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

?>
```

What you need to change is `sl`, `tl` and `q` values.

`sl` = Input language

`tl` = Output language

`q` = Your text, that will be translated

The response will look like this:

```
[[["Hallo Welt","Hello World","",""]],,"en",,[["Hallo Welt",[1],true,false,999,0,2,0]],[["Hello World",1,[["Hallo Welt",999,true,false]],[[0,11]],"Hello World"]],,,[["en"]],70]
```

Shouldn't be to difficult to extract the first array.